# What does $\nabla_L$ mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, complex-geometry

Given a $(1,0)$ smooth tangent vector field $L$ in $\Bbb C^n$, that is
$$
L=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}
$$
where $a_j$'s are complex valued functions, differentiable in the real sense, what does
$$
\nabla_L
$$
mean?
Someone told me that is an operator which, on gradients
$$
\nabla r=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_{z_j}r\cdot\partial_{z_j}+\partial_{\overline{z_j}}r\cdot\partial_{\overline{z_j}}
$$
behaves as follows
$$
\nabla_L\nabla r
=\sum_{j=1}^nL\left(\partial_{z_j}r\right)\cdot\partial_{z_j}+L\left(\partial_{\overline{z_j}}r\right)\cdot\partial_{\overline{z_j}}
$$
that is, it acts on the coefficients, but I would like to understand something more about it.
Can someone give me some reference, some hint?

Comment: Looks like [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) to me.